# java scripts is not launching on chrome

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

localhost:8080 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ttL.png)

This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Uh .. I've just noticed, that JS in Firefox is not lunching either ... There might be another word which would describe better what you actually mean ..?

Comment: how is anyone supposed to answer this? please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was practicing java script in visual stdio code and i installed Debugger for Chrome. but whenever I debug & Launch the browser shows "localhost:8080" && "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."